# django giving cryptic error for foreignkey

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error for a django model:

`ProgrammingError at /admin/notifications/eventtoken/
column notifications_eventtoken.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...ications_eventtoken" INNER JOIN "users_user" ON ( "notificat...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "notifications_eventtoken.used_at".`

I added a foreign key for user like this:

```
class EventToken(models.Model):
    token = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=False)
    used_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

it works when I remove the user field, but breaks otherwise and I can't tell much from the error message.

Comment: Can you please add the full error stack trace?

Comment: Did you run the migration after adding the new `user` field? i.e. is your database table up to date with your model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It works when I remove the user field.

This is because your database is missing a column that you have programmed in your EventToken class which I'm guessing is inside of `notifications/models.py`. This is why it is called a `ProgrammingError`.

There are several ways to solve this:

**1.** Delete your entire database and sync it again! Not recommended for anything running on production, but for test projects really doesn't hurt much.

**2.** Use a tool like [south](https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or the [django migrate app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/) (depending on which django version you're using) to automate adding a table to your database using the manage.py script. Edit: this solution is the most viable as it's quick and adheres to DRY principles when working across multiple development environments.

**3a.** Manually go into your database using a command line tool and add the missing column. If I haven't made it clear... you're saying "I want to save the user_id" foreign key in this table" while your table is saying back "There is nowhere to save this ID." ...)

**3b.** Use a database GUI (like PGadmin for postgresql) and add the user_id column to your notifications_eventtoken database table.

**4.** <strike>Delete the user field in the EventToken class!</strike> Don't do this, but understand it works because it clears the logical discrepancy.

Comment: Suggest that option 2 here is the one you want to look into, as it will have other benefits and prevent similar problems from happening in the future.